# How can I prove that a linear map $f$ where $f^3=f$ is diagonializeable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

The exam question was:

> $f$ is a linear map where $f^3=f,$ prove that it is diagonizable.

It was a linear algebra exam.

I asked the tutor if $f$ is a matrix since we only defined that a matrix can be diagonizable not any linear map, but he answered that we should prove it for linear maps in general. (Maybe iI missed something in the lectures?)

So $I$ wrote down that $f^3-f=0$ and that we can factor everything out like so:
$$f(f+1)(f-1)=0 $$
And argued that this is the minimal polynomial for the function and since its linear factors are different it means that f is diagonizable.

However as far as I know this holds only for matrices?
Is this approach correct/applicable for linear maps ? Was my tutor perhaps wrong? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138679/discussion-on-question-by-100xln2-how-can-i-prove-that-a-linear-map-f-where-f).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is a linear map such that $f^3=f$. Define the following:
$$
p_{0}=(1-f^2),\\p_{1}=\frac{1}{2}(f^2+f),\\ p_{-1}=\frac{1}{2}(f^2-f).
$$
Note that $p_{0}+p_{1}+p_{-1}=1$. It is not hard to verify that each of these is a projection, meaning that they are idempotent. For example,
$$
     p_0^2=1-2f^2+f^4=1-2f^2+f^2=1-f^2=p_0,\\
     p_1^2=\frac{1}{4}(f^4+2f^3+f^2)=\frac{1}{4}(f^2+2f+f^2)=\frac{1}{2}(f^2+f)=p_1, \\
   p_{-1}^2=\frac{1}{4}(f^4-2f^3+f^2)=\frac{1}{4}(f^2-2f+f^2)=\frac{1}{2}(f^2-f)=p_{-1}
$$
And these are pairwise disjoint, meaning that $p_jp_k=0$ for $j\ne k$. These are projections onto the eigenspaces of $f$ with eigenvalues $0,1,-1$. Therefore,
$$
      f = f(p_0+p_1+p_{-1})=p_1-p_{-1}
$$
So $f$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0,1,-1$.